# Running VB Macros via Python

Tags: python-3.x, excel, vba

I am using python to run VBA Macros. All of them work except for one. I don't get any errors but it is suppose to populate two sheets. One of the sheets gets populated and one does not. I only face this issue when I run through python, it works when you do it manually. Initially in a previous excel after explicitly declaring variables and referencing the worksheet in which the macro is(in VBA) that had worked. Now it does not as there have been some changes made in the xlsm. I am running the macro in python via Sheet.Application.Run(MacroName). Has anyone ever faced something like this. No errors, the macro works partially.

Comment: Sounds like the problem is with the VBA, but you've not included that in your post, so it's not clear what we could suggest as possible fixes.

Comment: A sample of the Macro code. Sub MyMacro()
    Dim ws As Workbook
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook
    Dim cn As WorkbookConnection

    For Each cn In ws.Connections
        If cn.Name = "Query" Then
            cn.Refresh
            Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:05") ' Delay for 5 seconds
        End If
    Next cn

Comment: ADditional saw that in the queries tab in excel for that query it said 'download did not complete' and also said loaded in worksheet. I don't think there is an authentication issue otherwise it should have said so

Comment: I now see that in query view it says 'Download did not complete' But load status is loaded and in the editor I see the correct data. When you select view in worksheet it even selects the right size of the data but there is no data in the sheet